# ASP.Net Core:Claims Transformation and Authorization Policy

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Please have a look at this url first https://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/claims-transformation-and-authorization-policy-in-aspnet5-mvc6

```
public virtual Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
 {
 if (principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
 {
 // get this from cache or db
 var country = "Pakistan";
 (principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).AddClaim(new Claim("Nationality", country));
 }
 return Task.FromResult(principal);
 }
```

when `TransformAsync()` will be called.......how to use it ?

```
[Authorize(Policy = "MustBePakistani")]
    public IActionResult Message()
    {
        return Content("Hi Pakistani");
    }
```

when Message action will be called then how asp.net mvc system will be able to understand what is user's nationality.....**is it pakistani or indian ?**

guide me how does it work. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to above two segments of the code in your question, you still need to add policy to authorization services in `Startup.cs`.

Example,

```
public class Startup
{    
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      ...    
      services.AddAuthorization(options =>
      {
         options.AddPolicy("MustBePakistani", policy => 
            policy.RequireClaim("Nationality", "Pakistan"));
      });
      services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();
      ...
   }

   private class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
   {
      // Can consume services from DI as needed, including scoped DbContexts
      public ClaimsTransformer(IHttpContextAccessor httpAccessor)
      {
      }

      public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
      {
         if (principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
         {
            // get this from cache or db
            var country = "Pakistan";
            (principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity)
               .AddClaim(new Claim("Nationality", country));
         }
         return Task.FromResult(principal);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: please tell me best place from where i can call MyClaimsTransformer() ?